# Github Pull Request Plugin

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I'm trying to setup the pull request plugin. I've configured it as suggested in the documentation but if I specify the branch to build as ${sha1} then that variable doesn't seem to be resolved. So in my logs:

```
Building in workspace /Users/sat/.jenkins/jobs/JenkinsTest/workspace
> /usr/local/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> /usr/local/bin/git config remote.origin.url git@githubenterprise.parc.com:stucker/tester.git
Fetching upstream changes from git@githubenterprise.parc.com:stucker/tester.git
> /usr/local/bin/git --version
> /usr/local/bin/git fetch --tags --progress git@githubenterprise.parc.com:stucker/tester.git   +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
> /usr/local/bin/git rev-parse origin/${sha1}^{commit}
> /usr/local/bin/git rev-parse ${sha1}^{commit}
```

But I don't know why that wouldn't work. This is coming off of a push triggered by the standard web hook

Comment: It might help if you'd share either screenshot or XML of the Jenkins job configuration. Have you pointed the WebHook URL to your Jenkins instance in the GitHub repository settings?

Comment: Do you get "No candidate revisions"? Can you try as in https://github.com/janinko/ghprb/issues/5#issuecomment-9661803?

Answer (score 3):

I found that you can't run the regular build hook and the pull request on the same job - I had to have separate jobs - one for doing a regular build, and one for doing a pull request build. With that everything works fine.

Comment: Good feedback. +1. I'll keep my answer for others in a similar situation but with separate jobs.

Comment: To make it more precise: the only difference between "regular build" and "pull-request build" here is how it was triggered. You can't trigger manually a build having a branch specifier set to `${sha1}` because it fails as above. You have to temporarily mark it as a parametrised build and introduce a string parameter of name `sha1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you get

```
Failed to rev-parse: origin/${sha1}
No candidate revisions
```

, it could be related to [issue 5](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb/issues/5).

A couple of suggestions:

- [5#issuecomment-14308061](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb/issues/5#issuecomment-14308061):
  I just had the same issue with v1.5 and I got it solved by cloning the job and deleting the old one.
- [5#issuecomment-19826662](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb/issues/5#issuecomment-19826662):
  In my case, "`Branches to build`" field in jenkins configuration form was like "`feature/abc/main`". My colleague [`@defragged`](https://github.com/defragged) has suggested to specify branch name without forward slashes ("`/`"). So I checked out new branch "`abcMain`" of "feature/abc/main" and build the job. It worked for me.
- [5#issuecomment-24628027](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb/issues/5#issuecomment-24628027):
  I was having the same problem with a Github Pull Request job, and it turned out I was missing the necessary refspec "`+refs/pull/:refs/remotes/origin/pr/`" from my job.
- [JENKINS-20502](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20502) "Cannot find any revision to build on clean workspace" (which doesn't seem to be in included in a Jenkins release yet)
- Other [open issues](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&jqlQuery=project%20=%20JENKINS%20AND%20status%20in%20%28Open,%20%22In%20Progress%22,%20Reopened%29%20AND%20component%20=%20%27ghprb%27) for the [GitHub pull request builder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin) (repo [`janinko/ghprb`](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb), forked at [jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin)), like [issue 17097](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17097).